# How can create WorkerParameters

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Worker's `Worker()` is `@Deprecated` , so need use

```
public Worker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }
```

but the WorkerParameters's constructor is `@hide`.

so, how can create WorkerParameters instance?

---

This library is the latest version of Android background task scheduling library, but this library has recently updated the API to mark the old creation method of the core class as discarded

Now, I don't know how to create this core class, because one of the parameters doesn't expose the constructor, nor do I find the way Factory / Builder works

So let me see if there is anyone who can help me in the great Stack Overflower.

The core class is Worker， params is WorkerParameters

Comment: Can you elaborate your question some more?

Comment: I want to use `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/android.arch.work/work-runtime/1.0.0-alpha09` library . The library is android workmanager library.

Comment: And what's your concern though?

Comment: I update the question，I want to know how can get the `WorkerParameters`

Comment: If you know this library before, you can go and have a look.

If this version has not read the code, we can see if we can solve this problem together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so query for you is that from latest library version of **`WorkManager`** *(dependency : **android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha09**)*,

Theres's constructor changed from

**`Worker()`**

to

**`Worker(@NonNull Context appContext, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams)`**.

Which means that default constructor is now no longer useful *(Deprecated, Marked as it should be removed on future versions)* & we're now on `parameterized constructor`.

Now, if you've noticed that when we use our **`Worker`**, we're not directly creating new `object` of it, instead we do something like this,

```
OneTimeWorkRequest.from(FooWorker.class) // We pass Class<?> obj of our worker here, or in PeriodicWorkRequest-it's the same
```

(Passing class Object of our `Worker` to our `WorkRequest`)

this means that **`WorkParameters`** are something that is provided by **`DefaultWorkerFactory`** internally. So you don't have to worry about it because, we're not going to create new object of **`Worker`** by ourself, unless you want any customized setup *(Which is now possible by this version & it's good)*.

---

> Also, from latest API changes on **September 19, 2018**
>
> - You can now create your own `Worker` instances at runtime by specifying a `WorkerFactory` as part of the `WorkManager.Configuration`.
>     The fallback factory is `DefaultWorkerFactory`, which matches behavior
>     of previous versions of `WorkManager`.
> - The default constructors for `Worker` and `NonBlockingWorker` are now marked as deprecated. Please use the new constructor `(Worker(Context, WorkerParameters))` and call `super(Context, WorkerParameters);` future
>     versions of `WorkManager` will remove the default constructor.

So now, it's the reason this question is all about, that what if i want to create **`WorkerParameters`**?

Answer is that before you can create **`WorkerParameters`**, you'll need to override default behaviour of `WorkManager` library and provide your own customized `WorkManager.Configuration` & by that creating your own `Worker`, at Runtime by providing `WorkerParameters` to it. *(This is the case where we need to provide **WorkerParameters**, you might not wanna do that if you're just using WorkManager functionalities out of the box)*

---

There's GoogleCodeLab's [**example**](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#0) which beautifully explains `WorkManager` (You can see [**here**](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#3) how it's done with new constructor).

### Conclusion:

Let's say you have got a **Worker** class called `FooWorker`, then your code will look like this:

```
public class FooWorker extends Worker {
    public FooWorker(
            @NonNull Context appContext,
            @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(appContext, workerParams);
    }

    private static final String TAG = FooWorker.class.getSimpleName();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Worker.Result doWork() {
        // Do some work & return appropriate result.
    }
}
```

and initialize like this

```
//Init WorkManager
private WorkManager mWorkManager;
mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
// Enqueue our work to manager
mWorkManager.enqueue(OneTimeWorkRequest.from(FooWorker.class)); // Here, we're not creating new FooWorker(); & we don't need to worry about `WorkerParameters` for now.
```

So there's no case to access/create **constructor/object** of `WorkerParamters`.

I hope this answer satisfies your question and helps.

Comment: @K.Cai let me know if you still got any doubts.

Comment: @JeelVankhede
Your description how does it work didn't help when you have some base class from which you extend all your jobs... Look at this my demo: https://gist.github.com/mtrakal/9454da3b1b950318d12618bd78e11184 and FIXME comment. 

I'm not able to rewrite it to working solution from previous version of lib

Comment: @mtrakal the link you provided is custom implementation of **worker library** over base provided. solution i provided is standard out of the box google provides and it's explanation to the question.

Comment: What if I want to start a new activity from the Worker class?

Comment: I would suggest to go with this usecase for starting activity from workmanager https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running