# Android. Could not instantiate Worker

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager

I want to pre-populate my Room database from the json file in the assets folder. I follow the [Google Sunflower sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower). I copied the SeedDatabaseWorker class:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import androidx.work.Worker
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters
import com.dmitrysimakov.gymlab.data.GymLabDb
import com.dmitrysimakov.gymlab.data.entity.Training
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader
import javax.inject.Inject

class SeedDatabaseWorker(val context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams) {
    private val TAG = SeedDatabaseWorker::class.java.simpleName

    @Inject lateinit var database: GymLabDb

    override fun doWork(): Worker.Result {
        val plantType = object : TypeToken<List<Training>>() {}.type
        var jsonReader: JsonReader? = null

        return try {
            val inputStream = context.assets.open("training.json")
            jsonReader = JsonReader(inputStream.reader())
            val plantList: List<Training> = Gson().fromJson(jsonReader, plantType)
            database.trainingDao().insert(plantList)
            Worker.Result.SUCCESS
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error seeding database", ex)
            Worker.Result.FAILURE
        } finally {
            jsonReader?.close()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Dagger 2, so instead of doing this: [Sunflower AppDatabase](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/data/AppDatabase.kt), I do this:

```
import android.arch.persistence.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase
import android.arch.persistence.room.Room
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase
import androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder
import androidx.work.WorkManager
import com.dmitrysimakov.gymlab.GymLabApp
import com.dmitrysimakov.gymlab.data.GymLabDb
import com.dmitrysimakov.gymlab.workers.SeedDatabaseWorker
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module(includes = [ViewModelModule::class])
class AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDb(app: GymLabApp): GymLabDb {
        return Room
                .databaseBuilder(app, GymLabDb::class.java, "gymlab.db")
                .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                    override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                        super.onCreate(db)
                        val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SeedDatabaseWorker>().build()
                        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(request)
                    }
                })
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideTrainingDao(db: GymLabDb) = db.trainingDao()
}
```

But I can't inject the database that has not yet been created. So, how can I access the dao?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I couldn't inject my database into the Worker. I found the solution here: [AndroidWorkerInjection](https://gist.github.com/ferrerojosh/82bd92748f315155fa6a842f4ed64c82)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `SeedDatabaseWorker` is still based on **`Worker()`** which is deprecated now, so you need to use **`Worker(Context, WorkerParameters)`** this constructor.

Check my answer from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52432391/10271334), it'll help you understand `WorkManager` library.

### Edit :

You can now check [Worker](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/workers/SeedDatabaseWorker.kt) from that Sunflower demo, it's updated.

Comment: @DmitrySimakov , Just go through that example of sunflower once, i'm sure you'll understand it.

Comment: but anyway I can't inject database, so I can't get the dao.

Comment: I came here due to issues with *alpha09*. You mention correctly the ```Worker()``` is deprecated. However I can confirm this constructor is still used and not the newer ```Worker(Context, WorkerParameters)```. For now I added **both** constructors to my worker implementation.

Also I made the mistake of making the worker *package protected*. The worker implementation needs to be **```public```**. (I'm using the Java version.)

Comment: Yep, and `Worker()` is scheduled to be removed in future releases, that's why suggested you to use `Worker(Context, WorkerParameters)`.