# How to pass the worker parameters to WorkManager class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

In one of my android(with Kotlin) app I want to use WorkManager class as a generic one.
This is my class where I want to use it as generic by passing expected params:

```
class CommonWorkManager<P, R> (appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(appContext, workerParams)
{
    var lambdaFunction: ((P) -> R)? = null

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        lambdaFunction
        return Result.SUCCESS
    }
}
```

This is how I am trying to create an instance of this class:

```
CommonWorkManager<Unit, Unit>(context!!, ).lambdaFunction= {
    presenter?.fetchMasterData()
}
```

So How can I pass `workerParams` as a second param.

Here 'P' is Parameter and 'R' is Return type in `CommonWorkManager<P, R>`

Comment: i think that question have your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422361/how-can-create-workerparameters

Answer (score 2):

It seems we can't create instances of `WorkerParameters` because it has hidden constructor with annotation `@RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP)`.
According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics#workflow) we don't create instances of `Worker` subclass, the library does it for us:

> First, you would define your `Worker` class, and override its `doWork()` method. Your worker class specifies how to perform the operation, but doesn't have any information about when the task should run. Next, you create a `OneTimeWorkRequest` object based on that `Worker`, then enqueue the task with `WorkManager`:

```
val work = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(CommonWorkManager::class.java).build()
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(work)
```

We can conclude that we can't create universal `Worker`, i.e. `CommonWorkManager<P, R>` in your case. `WorkManager` is intended for the specific tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, This is to just start work, but I want to create an instance by passing expected parameters to it and assign value to the `lambdaFunction` variable

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55888404/6723193)?

Comment: @Amg91 it's just about sending object! what about interface (Unit in Kotlin)? I'm looking for a way to use  one Worker class and use it for all part of my project. Do you have any idea to do that?