# How can I pass a Lambda to the MyWorkManager class?

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, android-workmanager

I'm using kotlin for android and I'm trying to create a generic Worker class in which I can pass a lambda which can be called from doWork() method.

```
class BaseWorker(val context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams) {
    override fun doWork(): Result {

        //Passed from the activity while creating the work request
        someLambda()

        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

The problem is I am not instantiating the `BaseWorker` class by calling the constructor.
Is it possible to pass the Lambda using `setInputData()` of `OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder` class.

I referred [How to pass the worker parameters to WorkManager class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53850469/how-to-pass-the-worker-parameters-to-workmanager-class) where the constructor of the class is being called which I think is not the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Data`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Data.Builder) class in WorkManager it's only intended for base types and their arrays. You cannot use it to pass a lamba.

A possible solution is to customize WorkManager's initialization, [as explained in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration.html), and use a custom WorkerFactory to add a parameter to the constructor that you can use to retrieve the lambda. Keep in mind that you are configuring WorkManager just once, at initialization time. This means that you can pass directly the lambda as the additional parameter, but it will not be possible to customize it for each WorkRequest.

Depending on what you want to achieve exactly, something similar can be used as a starting point:

```
// provide custom configuration
val config = Configuration.Builder()
        .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.INFO)
        .setWorkerFactory(MyWorkerFactory(lambda))
        .build()

//initialize WorkManager
WorkManager.initialize(this, config)

val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance()
```

And then have your WorkerFactory:

```
class MyWorkerFactory(private val lambda: Unit) : WorkerFactory() {
    override fun createWorker(appContext: Context,
                          workerClassName: String,
                          workerParameters: WorkerParameters): MyWorker {

        return MyWorker(appContext, workerParameters, lambda)
    }
}
```

You can then have your worker that use the new constructor:

```
class MyWorker(val context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters, private val lambda: Unit) : Worker(context, workerParams) {
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        //Passed from the WorkManager's configuration
        lambda()

        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

Remember to disable the default WorkManager initialization adding to the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<provider
          android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
          android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
          tools:node="remove" />
```

Comment: What is BlurWorker and _testContext

Comment: Sorry, just a copy&paste error. Let me know if this is clearer

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth revisiting your question to see what you are trying to do and why it's fundamentally flawed.  You are trying to pass a lambda from an Activity to a worker, which is something that runs in the background, even if the Activity is no longer around.  This doesn't make any sense.  Please don't do this - it's only going to result in memory leaks, crashes, and/or strange errors that will be hard for you to track down.  Remember that workers need to be able to be created from scratch when the OS tells your app to run them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you **CAN** do it ONLY using what WorkManager provides to us. IMO changing the WorkManager initialization is too complex/risk for a simple thing like this as suggested in the other answer.
WorkRequests accept ByteArray input, which can be any object, right? So, create a serialized object wrapping the lambda function that will be later called

Define a serializable wrapper class passing the lambda(logRequestTime): LambdaSerializable

```
package com.febaisi.lambdawithworkers
import java.io.Serializable

class LambdaSerializable(val logRequestTime: () -> (Unit)): Serializable {
}
```

Convert it to ByteArray and *put* it in the input object.

```
val lambdaObject = LambdaSerializable { //Lambda function
   Log.e("Lambda", "Request time was -> $requestTime") 
}
val input = Data.Builder()
.putByteArray(SimpleWorker.LAMBDA_OBJECT, serializeObject((lambdaObject as Object)))
.build()

val simpleWorker = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SimpleWorker::class.java)
.setInputData(input)
.build()

WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).enqueueUniqueWork("lambda_worker", ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, simpleWorker)
```

Call it from the worker. SimpleWorker

```
class SimpleWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
    Worker(context, workerParams) {

    companion object {
       val LAMBDA_OBJECT = "LAMBDA_OBJECT"
    }

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        Log.e("Lambda", "Executing worker - Sleeping for 5 seconds - Compare request vs current time")
        val lambdaSerializable = inputData.getByteArray(LAMBDA_OBJECT)?.let{ getByteInput(it) }

        runBlocking {
            delay(5000)
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd__HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())
            Log.e("Lambda", "Current time is -> ${sdf.format(Date())}")
            (lambdaSerializable as LambdaSerializable).logRequestTime() // High level - Calling Lambda
        }

        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

**FULL EXAMPLE HERE:** https://github.com/febaisi/LambdaWithWorkers/ 
Check logs to see lambda function being called.